# comparing attributes of 2 different turtles breed

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have 2 turtles bread:

```
globals [ max-applicant ]
breed [ applicants applicant ]
breed [ investors investor ]

applicants-own [ ask-amount applied? industry country-of-origin funded? ]
investors-own [ allowed-industries-list allowed-countries-list no-of-applicants-funded ]
```

I want to perform a transaction based on whether the investor is allowed to do business with the applicant's industry and country of origin. An Investors can only perform a limited number of transactions based on the `max-applicant` value

In the code below, I'm trying to select an investor that hasn't reached the max transaction limit and then select an applicant that meets the conditions of the selected investor and fund that applicant:

```
to close-deal
  let investorPerson one-of investors-here with [no-of-applicants-funded < max-applicant]
  if investorPerson != nobody  [
    ask investorPerson  [
      let applicantPerson one-of applicants-here with [
        industry member? [allowed-industries] and country-of-origin member? [allowed-countries] of myself
      ]
      if applicantPerson != nobody  [
        ask applicantPerson [
          set funded? TRUE
        ]
      ]
      set no-of-applicants-funded no-of-applicants-funded + 1
      
    ]
  ]
end
```

This code doesn't run. is this the right way to design this operation?

Comment: In general you should post a [mre]. Also, things like "it doesn't work" are not descriptive enough: do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say? If not, what is the unexpected behaviour? Etc. Anyway see below: I attempted an answer based on the elements we have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two problems:

1. See [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) the syntax of `member?`: it is *member? value list*, while in your code you have *value member? list*.
2. In the first of the two boolean statements where you use `member?`, you omitted the `of myself` that should address `[allowed-industries]`.

Combining the two points above, you should have:

```
let applicantPerson one-of applicants-here with [
        (member? industry [allowed-industries] of myself) AND (member? country-of-origin [allowed-countries] of myself)
      ]
```

The use of parentheses and the capitalisation of boolean operators are optional, just my own stylistic choice.

**Side note**: be aware that you are asking your `investorPerson` to

```
set no-of-applicants-funded no-of-applicants-funded + 1
```

outside of the command block that gets executed if there actually is an `applicantPerson`; i.e. your investors will increment `no-of-applicants-funded` even when `applicantPerson = NOBODY`.